# Can a C macro contain temporary variables?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a function that I need to macro'ize. The function contains temp variables and I can't remember if there are any rules about use of temporary variables in macro substitutions.

```
long fooAlloc(struct foo *f, long size)
{
   long      i1, i2;
   double   *data[7];

   /* do something */
   return 42;
}
```

MACRO Form:

```
#define ALLOC_FOO(f, size) \
{\
   long      i1, i2;\
   double   *data[7];\
\
   /* do something */ \
}
```

Is this ok? (i.e. no nasty side effect - other than the usual ones : not "type safe" etc). BTW, I know "macros are evil" - I simply have to use it in this case - not much choice.

Comment: Why do you need to macroize it?  If you're concerned about performance, then (a) chances are you're worrying needlessly (unless you've actually measured it and concluded that it's a significant bottleneck) and (b) you can achieve the same effect, in a more type-safe manner, by making the function `inline` (some older or Microsoft compilers might not support this).

Comment: @KeithThompson performance is not the issue here. I am writing an extension library and I need a wrapper function to do do some data marshalling. Macros simply provide a less error prone way of automagically generating a lot of "glue" code.

Comment: `return` inside a macro does not do what you appear to think it does.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I just found that out ... I'll modify the snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are only two conditions under which it works in any "reasonable" way.

1. The macro doesn't have a return statement.  You can use the `do while` trick.

   ```
   #define macro(x) do { int y = x; func(&y); } while (0)
   ```
2. You only target GCC.

   ```
   #define min(x,y) ({ int _x = (x), _y = (y); _x < _y ? _x : _y; })
   ```

It would help if you explain *why* you have to use a macro (does your office have "macro mondays" or something?).  Otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: Macro Mondays, and Micro Fridays... :-) That being said, I like using macros for one thing: to build an object with `__FILE__` , `__func__`, and `__LINE__`. Much more practical than having to type all of those each time.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: But if the code already exists as a function, it can’t be using any of those.

Comment: That's why I would create a macro. I use that especially for logs. I create a log object which on destruction writes the string to a file/console/syslog... So I have a class and could _just_ create an object manually each time. With macros, it saves me to have to enter all of that information over and over again. My macros are at the very end of this [log.h header](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/blob/master/libsnapwebsites/src/snapwebsites/log.h). It could be that we don't have the full picture from OP, too.

Comment: The fact that we don’t have the story from OP is exactly the point I was making. The OP says “have to use macros”… but without any explanation for why the OP claims to need to use macros, guesses in the dark are unlikely to get us any closer to understanding what the OP is trying to solve with macros.

Answer (score 7):

C macros are only (relatively simple) textual substitutions.

So the question you are maybe asking is: can I create blocks (also called compound statements) in a function like in the example below?

```
void foo(void)
{
    int a = 42;
    {   
        int b = 42;
        {
            int c = 42; 
        } 
    }
}
```

and the answer is yes.

Now as @DietrichEpp mentioned it in his answer, if the macro is a compound statement like in your example, it is a good practice to enclose the macro statements with `do { ... } while (0)` rather than just `{ ... }`. The link below explains what situation the `do { ... } while (0)` in a macro tries to prevent:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html

Also when you write a function-like macro always ask yourself if you have a real advantage of doing so because most often writing a function instead is better.

Answer (score 7):

This is mostly OK, except that macros are usually enclosed with `do { ... } while(0)` (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro) for explanations):

```
#define ALLOC_FOO(f, size) \
    do { \
        long      i1, i2;\
        double   *data[7];\
        /* do something */ \
    } while(0)
```

Also, as far as your original `fooAlloc` function returns `long` you have to change your macro to store the result somehow else. Or, if you use GCC, you can try [compound statement](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) extension:

```
#define ALLOC_FOO(f, size) \
    ({ \
        long      i1, i2;\
        double   *data[7];\
        /* do something */ \
        result; \
    })
```

Finally you should care of possible side effects of expanding macro argument. The usual pattern is defining a temporary variable for each argument inside a block and using them instead:

```
#define ALLOC_FOO(f, size) \
    ({ \
        typeof(f) _f = (f);\
        typeof(size) _size = (size);\
        long      i1, i2;\
        double   *data[7];\
        /* do something */ \
        result; \
    })
```

Comment: Aren't `__f` and `__size` reserved?

Comment: @Zaxter Strictly speaking, yes, they are.

Answer (score 7):

First, I strongly recommend inline functions. There are very few things macros can do and they can't, and they're much more likely to do what you expect.

One pitfall of macros, which I didn't see in other answers, is shadowing of variable names.
Suppose you defined:

```
#define A(x) { int temp = x*2; printf("%d\n", temp); }
```

And someone used it this way:

```
int temp = 3;
A(temp);
```

After preprocessing, the code is:

```
int temp = 3;
{ int temp = temp*2; printf("%d\n", temp); }
```

This doesn't work, because the internal temp shadows the external.
The common solution is to call the variable `__temp`, assuming nobody will define a variable using this name (which is a strange assumption, given that you just did it).

Comment: Well, to make a temporary variable's name crazily unique, you might generate a UUID for it :)

Answer (score 3):

Eldar's answer shows you most of the pitfalls of macro programming and some useful (but non standard) gcc extension.

If you want to stick to the standard, a combination of macros (for genericity) and `inline` functions (for the local variables) can be useful.

```
inline
long fooAlloc(void *f, size_t size)
{
   size_t      i1, i2;
   double   *data[7];

   /* do something */
   return 42;
}


#define ALLOC_FOO(T) fooAlloc(malloc(sizeof(T)), sizeof(T))
```

In such a case using `sizeof` only evaluates the expression for the type at compile time and not for its value, so this wouldn't evaluate `F` twice.

BTW, "sizes" should usually be typed with `size_t` and not with `long` or similar.

*Edit:* As to Jonathan's question about `inline` functions, I've written up something about the `inline` model of C99, [here](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/).

Comment: Should that be `static inline ...`?

Comment: @Jonathan, why would that be?

Comment: You need to be extremely careful with `inline` in C (IMO).  The three most relevant questions that I found on SO are ["Inline definitions?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454690/inline-definitions), ["Is inline without static or extern ever useful in C99?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99), and ["extern inline?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline), not in any particular order.  (And, for the record, I'm not pontificating on the issue; I was asking a question.)

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, no problem, I was taking it as such, just a question. Please see the link in my edit on how I think one should program `inline` functions with C99.

Comment: Of all approaches I read, this worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work as you use a block structure and the temp variables are declared in the inner scope of this block.

Note the last \ after the } is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

A not perfect solution: (does not work with recursive macros, for example multiple loops inside each other)

```
#define JOIN_(X,Y) X##Y
#define JOIN(X,Y) JOIN_(X,Y)
#define TMP JOIN(tmp,__LINE__)

#define switch(x,y) int TMP = x; x=y;y=TMP

int main(){
  int x = 5,y=6;
  switch(x,y);
  switch(x,y);
}
```

will become after running the preprocessor:

```
int main(){
   int x=5,y=6;
   int tmp9 = x; x=y; y=tmp9;
   int tmp10 = x; x=y; y=tmp10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They can.  They often shouldn't.

Why does this function need to be a macro?  Could you inline it instead?

Comment: Except you'll find as your program grows and support issues arise, maintaining code generated by macros is NOT less error prone.  It's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using c++ use inline, or use -o3 with gcc it will inline all functions for you.
I still don't understand why you need to macroize this function.